# Calling signOut() method of Google Plus integration in android throws java.lang.IllegalStateException: GoogleApiClient is not connected yet

Tags: android, google-plus

I want to call signOut method lying in say Activity1 from Activity2.
But whenever I am moving to some other Activities, I am getting an exception with message GoogleApiClient not connected yet.
This is possible if I am doing  all the stuffs in a same Activity, but I don't want to do it so.

So please give an example where signOut() of GooglePlus can be called from other Activities.

Comment: `GoogleApiClient.connect()` must be called and `onConnected` method callback should be received before you can do `signOut()`. Share your code   if you want someone to point out what's wrong exactly

Answer (score 0):

```
  if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
                new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(Status status) {
                        // [START_EXCLUDE]

                    }
                });
    }
```